# How to make "sort by location" the default option in Outline view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the outline view, it is sorted by category by default. How to make it sort by location by default?

[image]

I went to Google to search the relevant content, but can not find the answer, so to ask.

I know that in the configuration "breadcrumbs.SymbolSortOrde", and the default is "position", but the configuration items like has nothing to do with the Settings on the picture is, at least in my here.

Comment: Do you mean `Sort By: Position`?  It should remember the last `Sort By` you choose.

Comment: @Mark When opening a new folder, the last choice will not be remembered.